# Magento Price index not working?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I have problem regarding magento price index. My price index not working , I am try to do more things in this but its not working. I am facing same issue in my different site. 
I am using magento 1.7.2 , 1.8, 1.8.2

Please help me to sort out this issue.

Thanks

Jitendra

Comment: What is not working? What have you tried already?

Comment: I am try to index price but not get success . I am try to programmatically and shell command also but not done

Comment: Did you ever solve this? If not, is there an extension you use that is common to all your different sites experiencing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reindex via shell:

```
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_price
```

Or programmatically:

```
$price_process = Mage::getModel('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('catalog_product_price');
$price_process->reindexAll();
```

Comment: I am try to both but not done I am get some error in shell command ,like .. insert into .(ca.., Array()) like something

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue for below step

1) take database backup

2) select this table index

3) delete foreign key and reference key after delete all the index data

4) do reindex all

5) its working